# Making a matrix from another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with 1 column, x rows. My second matrix has to be the first few values of that matrix concatenated to the last values of that matrix.

Example: 
a=[0:1:10]
b=[0,1,9,10]

Question: How do I build b, by using a?

Comment: `b = a(1:firstfew, end-lastfew+1:end)`

Comment: `b = a; b(firstfew+1:end-lastfew) = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the number of values you want to extract off of each end is `n`. The `horzcat` command let's you horizontally concatenate matrices.

```
n=2;
a=[0:1:10];
b=horzcat(a(1:n),a(end-n+1:end))
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g. for letting b be the first two columns of a and the two last columns of a concatenated: `b = [a(:, 1:2), a(:, size(a, 2) - 1:size(a, 2))]`.

Example:

```
>> a = [0:1:10]

a =

 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> b = [a(:, 1:2), a(:, size(a, 2) - 1:size(a, 2))]

b =

 0     1     9    10
```